# I have error with Comparison arguments must be compatible types: Boolean, String

Tags: apex

```
 @istest
    static void testsendsmswithexception(){
        id invalidAppId = null;
        string invalidEmailtype ='CONFIRMATION';
        
        test.starttest();
        try {
             CastAlertService.sendSMS(invalidAppId,invalidEmailtype);
            System.assertEquals(false,'Expected exception was not thrown.');
        }catch(exception ex) {
            system.assertEquals('CastAlert',ex.getmessage(),'Unexpected exception message');
        }
        Test.stopTest();
        }
```

Comment: Including details is very important here. This particular situation is easy enough for experienced eyes to see, but in general you should include the _stack trace_ along with the error message and also specifically call out which line the error is complaining about.

Answer (score 2):

`System.assertEquals` and `Assert.areEqual` require their first two parameters to be a compatible data type. `false` is a `Boolean`, `'Expected exception was not thrown.'` is a `String`. These are not compatible types, because `false == 'Expected exception was not thrown'` isn't a legal comparison.

```java
// Compile error: Comparison arguments must be compatible types: Boolean, String
Boolean value = false == 'Expected exception was not thrown';
```

You most likely meant to write:

```java
System.assert(false,'Expected exception was not thrown.');
```

Though in modern Apex, it would be more appropriate to write:

```java
Assert.fail('Expected exception was not thrown.');
```